# TimeLinePlot tooltip shows Day rather than Year

Tags: plotting, bugs, date-and-time

**Bug introduced in 12.0 or earlier, completely fixed in 13.0.0**

**Update 2021-05-28**

Granularity bug not fixed in **12.3.0**

---

The originally reported tooltip bug has been fixed in 12.2.0, however, now in some cases, the granularity is completely ignored in the tooltip. e.g. using `dates` from @kglr's answer

[image]

---

Tooltip bug not fixed in 12.1.1.

The `Part::partw:` error has been fixed in 12.1.0. Tooltip bug has not.

---

**Update 2019-11-28**

WRI has confirmed that this is a bug.

**Update 2019-11-25**

The workaround suggested by @alx works if all of the dates have the same granularity. While experimenting with the workaround suggested by @kglr I ran into another issue.

```
TimelinePlot[{
  DateObject[{2019}, "Year"] -> "Foo",
  DateObject[{2019, 11}, "Month"] -> "Bar"
  }]
```

Generates the error

> Part::partw: Part 2 of {{3.75529*10^9,2019,{0.01,0}}} does not exist.

Reported to WRI CASE:4360060

**Original question**

The tooltip shows "Day: 2019" even though the `DateObject` represents a Year. Is this a bug? How to show "Year: 2019" in the tooltip?

```
TimelinePlot[DateObject[{2019}, "Year"] -> "Foo"]
```

[image]

```
DateObject[{2019}, "Year"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** For input data with mixed date granularity:

```
dates = {DateObject[{2019, 11}, "Month"] -> "Month", 
  DateObject[{2019}, "Year"] -> "Year", 
  DateObject[{2019, 5, 15}, "Week"] -> "Week", 
  DateObject[{2020, 10}, "Year"] -> "Year2", 
  DateObject[{2019, 10}, "Quarter"] -> "Quarter"}; 

TimelinePlot[Tooltip[#, #] -> #2 & @@@ Sort[dates]]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

An alternative work-around is to wrap `DateObject`s with `Tooltip`:

```
TimelinePlot[Tooltip[#, #] & @ DateObject[{2019}, "Year"] -> "Foo"]
```

[image]

```
TimelinePlot[Tooltip[#, #]& @ DateObject[{2019, 11}, "Month"] -> "Foo"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

From `InputForm[TimelinePlot[DateObject[{2019}, "Year"] -> "Foo"]]` one can see, that MMA uses `Day` as granularity for `DateObject`s. So, one possible solution is to change these objects to the needed form:

```
TimelinePlot[DateObject[{2019}, "Year"] -> "Foo"] /. 
 DateObject[a__, "Day", b__] :> DateObject[a, "Year", b]
```

Another possibility is using custom `LabelingFunction`:

```
TimelinePlot[DateObject[{2019}, "Year"] -> "Foo", 
 LabelingFunction -> (DateObject[FromAbsoluteTime@First@#, "Year"] &)]
```